# Is it possible to establish an association in Doctrine2 without target entity at hand?

Tags: orm, doctrine, symfony, doctrine-orm

There is a `ManyToOne` association defined between entities `Pattern` and `Category` (Pattern is an owning side of the relation). Category has many patterns, pattern belongs to one category. So there is a field `Pattern.category` with `@ManyToOne` Doctrine annotation.

Now, in my scenario I have the **id** of the Category entity (posted from form) that I want assign to Pattern.category field of the newly created Pattern (which will be persisted), but I don't want to load this Category entity - I don't need it, I just want to create a Pattern entity, assign it to a Category (which id I have), and persist it. It seems strange to me, that I have to load the Category entity just to establish the connection, when all I really need is just an id, which I already have.

Maybe it smells like using relational database concepts with ORM, but it seems completely pointless to load this entity just to establish connection, when I know id of that target entity.

I am new to Doctrine btw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Reference Proxy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#proxy-objects):

```
$category = $em->getReference('Category', $id);
$pattern->setCategory($category);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for: "This is useful, for example, as a performance enhancement, when you want to establish an association to an entity for which you have the identifier."

Comment: The documentation URL has changed to http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#proxy-objects